# Generic field in non-generic class

Tags: java, generics

I want to include a field declared as `Map<Class<T>, MyClass<T>>` inside a non-generic class.

When I do this compiler throws an error. I am open to other suggestions to achieve what I am trying to do here (i.e.) a place where I can store such a map but without compilation error.

I am trying to keep track of all the relevant persistence objects depending upon the class of the object. So when I try to do this

```
private <R> Map<Class<? extends R>, MyPersistenceClass<R>> classToPersistenceMap;
```

I get the following:

> R cannot be resolved into a type.

Comment: Can you share the [relevant part of the] code the class, and explain why you need such a map?

Comment: Could you post code? what error is he throwing?

Comment: @nullpointer I am trying my best not to use raw types to take advantage of the generics and not cast manually. So that when i retrieve values from the map for different class keys, the generic type of MyPersistence class is automatically inferred by the compiler, and the benefits I get there on.

Comment: Also why is the class that contains this suppose to be a *non-generic class.* ?

Comment: @nullpointer Because i need this class's instance not to be dependent on the type of classToPersistenceMap, I want the class's instance to hold a field which can store a Map between `Class<? extends R>` and `MyPersistenceClass<R>` for any R

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran how do you expect the compiler to know what that `R` is?

Comment: But in generic methods, declaring `private <R> void someMethod(Map<Class<? extends R>, MyPersistenceClass<R>> classToPersistenceMap)`, works... I am telling the compiler what <R> is before the return type. and as you said compiler understands what R is and compiles, but why not same with the field declaration?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should be told what 'T' is - thus in case the class where you define that field is not generic (it is not parameterized with 'T') it will not know what generic type the 'Class' should require.
So it is pointless to specify the generic parameter if you don't have a mean to transmit it from the client code.
You may want instead to declare the field as 
    `Map<Class<?>, MyClass<?>>`

Comment: But in generic methods, declaring `private <R> void someMethod(Map<Class<? extends R>, MyPersistenceClass<R>> classToPersistenceMap)`, works... I am telling the compiler what <R> is before the return type. and as you said compiler understands what R is and compiles, but why not same with the field declaration?